# Validate/coerce values when replacing an entire collection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a `my_obj` instance of `MyType` with a `my_collection` relationship for `RelType`, I have a validation method decorated with `@validates('my_collection')` that coerces appended dicts with a primary-key key/value pair into instances of `RelType`.

So, it works perfectly in this case:

```
my_obj.my_collection.append(RelType(rel_type_id=x))
```

And in this case, automatically coercing the values:

```
my_obj.my_collection.append({"rel_type_id": x})
```

However, the validation method is not called when the whole collection is replaced. It doesn't work for this case:

```
my_obj.my_collection = [{"rel_type_id": x}]
```

I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` because I'm trying to assign the dict directly, not an instance of `RelType`.

From the documentation, it looks like the only way to get it to work in that case is to have a custom collection class with a method tagged as  `@collection.converter`, but besides the extra complication of using a custom collection, it looks like that would just duplicate code that's already in the validator.

Am I missing something? Is there a better/easier way?

**UPDATE**

Here's a minimal example reproducing the problem, SQLAlchemy 1.1.5

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class RelType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rel_type'

    rel_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('my_type.my_type_id'))


class MyType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_type'

    my_type_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_collection = relationship('RelType')

    @validates('my_collection')
    def validate_my_collection(self, key, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, RelType):
            value = RelType(**value)

        return value


def main():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    obj = MyType(my_type_id=1)
    # this works
    obj.my_collection.append({'rel_type_id': 2})

    # but this immediately raises TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
    obj.my_collection = [{'rel_type_id': 1}]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlamin.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "sqlamin.py", line 51, in main
    obj.my_collection = [{'rel_type_id': 1}]
  File ".env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 224, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File ".env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1081, in set
    new_values, old_collection, new_collection)
  File ".env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 748, in bulk_replace
    constants = existing_idset.intersection(values or ())
  File ".env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 612, in intersection
    result._members.update(self._working_set(members).intersection(other))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: It's supposed to work. If you write a minimal example with the latest version of sqlalchemy it should work.

Comment: @univerio Are you sure about that? I added a minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: It looks like it's a problem unique to iterables. If you try `obj.my_collection = [1]` it does work. There might be some behavior specific to iterables. Weird.

Comment: @univerio Seems to be a problem with unhashable objects. It doesn't work with lists either, but it works with tuples and with a dict subclass implementing the `__hash__` method.

Comment: I would call this a bug tbh. If you look at `sqlalchemy.orm.collections` the reason it tries to hash the values is to diff between the old list and the new list to figure out how to fire events. Perhaps submit a pull request?

Comment: @univerio I'm starting to think that too. Let's see what zzzeek has to say about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is unexpected behavior, more of a design flaw than a bug. There's an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3896/bulk_replace-assumes-incoming-values-are#) opened for a better fix on 1.2, but meanwhile the workaround is using a custom collection with the `@collection.converter` decorator:

```
class MyCollection(list):
    @collection.converter
    def convert(self, value):
        return [RelType(**v) if not isinstance(v, RelType) else v for v in value]
```

And use that with the relationship:

```
my_collection = relationship('RelType', collection_class=MyCollection)
```

Unfortunately the `@collection.appender` also doesn't work for similar reasons, so you have to implement the validator and the converter to catch both append and replace cases.